# Move Button into grid space of a TabNavigator's tabs in Flex Builder

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3, mxml

I have a layout question for Tab Navigators in Adobe Flex 3.

Is it possible to insert a button that invades the grid space of the tabs?

I have a tab navigator component and I am dynamically adding sub components to tab navigator and I want squeeze a button inside the tab space. I don't want the button to be another tab.   And I don't want to use a TabBar for the tabs.

This graphic illustrates the problem.

This is the current layout I have

[image: Current Layout]

This is a mockup (photoshopped) of the layout I want. I basically want to shave some pixels off the layout.

[image: Desired Layout]

Is there a way to push the button down or manually override its layout position in MXXML or actionscript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would think if you put the elements in a Canvas (which allows you to lay out elements absolutely) rather than a VBox as it appears you are using now, you could force the Home button to display the way you want it to, ie:

```
<mx:Canvas>
   <mx:Button top="5" right="5" />
   <mx:TabNavigator top="5" left="5" right="5" />
</mx:Canvas>
```